# Replace box characters in Oracle SQL using regex replace

Tags: sql, oracle, informatica-cloud

How to replace the box characters from a table in oracle sql using regexp_replace?
I tried to specify the unicode escape sequence of the box character in regexp replace but it doesnt work, is there any other way to replace.

Query used:
select regexp_replace(colA,'[\u001A]','') from tableA;

Comment: can the unistr take multiple inputs like regexp_replace(colA, unistr('\001A, \F0A7'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
regexp_replace(colA, unistr('\001A'))
```

If you just want to replace one string, you don't need a regex, and the standard `replace` will perform better:

```
replace(colA, unistr('\001A'))
```

Comment: Thank you William, it worked!! i was trying to use regexp_replace as i had to filter out a range of characters like "\\u0000,\\u001a,[^\\u0000-\\uFFFF],\\u2FFF,\\uFFFD"